# How do I get elements of array generated by a XLSX module extracted excel file without getting undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I used the xlsx module in a node electron project to extract the content of an excel file

I am only able to extract the items in the first column successfully
But I am unable to extract the content of subsequent columns
Please advise me on how I can get the content of subsequent columns.

```
var XLSX = require("xlsx");
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(excelFile.path);
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;//gives sheet name
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list];
var dataArray = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
alert("dataArray is : " + dataArray);
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
var newData = dataArray.map(function (record) {
   
alert("rec 1 :"  + record[1])
alert("rec 2 :"  + record[2])
```

I attached screenshots of the alert pop-ups generated by javascript [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76p3m.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76p3m.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEbuZ.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEbuZ.png) and also a screenshot of the xlsx [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwf1M.png) file being uploaded and extracted
You can see from the screenshot that I extracted the content of the first column using record[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76p3m.png) which comes as 1

But the content of other columns come as undefined[image: undefined data extracted]
Why do other columns come as undefined and how do I get the content of other columns

Answer (score 0):

I was able to iterate using below code

```
 const workbook = XLSX.readFile(excelFile.path);
 var sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames;
 // alert("sheetnames :> " + sheetNames);
 var sheetIndex = 1;
    
 var df = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[sheetIndex-1]]);
 // alert(JSON.stringify(df));
 // alert(JSON.stringify(df, null, 4));

  // alert("df Length  :> " + df.length);
  df.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  var x = arrayItem;
  alert(JSON.stringify(x.ID));
   
  // alert(JSON.stringify(x, null, 4));

});
```